# Java text match e-mail

Tags: java, validation

I am new to regular expressions, but I want to learn. Here is the example of e-mail validation:

```
public class x 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*+@[a-zA-Z0-9]*[.]([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][a-z][a-z])";
        String text    = "g@gmail.co";
        System.out.println(text.matches(pattern));
    }
}
```

I tried to write email validation. Where I am wrong and what I could have optimized maybe? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This regex is fairly complete and a reasonable balance between speed, complexity and effectiveness:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

IMHO, the best regex learning site is [regular-expresssions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which also has [a discussion on email validation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (where I got this regex)

Answer (score 1):

It is not practical to accurately validate email addresses using regular expressions. The format of email addresses is extremely complex, as described informally on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) and more formally in the RFCs linked from that page.

As you see from the answers given by other people, any regular expression that tries to tackle something that complex is bound to be incomprehensible to humans; so you can never be sure that it's correct.

This is not just a theoretical problem. Any sophisticated email validation code that gets into the wild will hit cases that it can't handle surprisingly quickly. As an example from a closely related domain, I often have to lie about my name when talking to computers because it's got a hyphen in it.

You should think about what you are trying to achieve with your validation. What values would you like to exclude, and what is the cost of doing so? Really you want to exclude errors on the part of the user, most likely typos; but the huge majority of (likely) typos will result in a valid email address, so you won't catch those.

The only practical way to validate an email address is to send an email to it. If you really need an email address for your users, that's the only way you can ensure that you have a valid one.

Comment: I just want to learn regular expressions, e-mail validation is just an example

Comment: You may want to consider rewording your question, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class EmailValidator{

      private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;

      private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
                   "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@
                   [A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

      public EmailValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
      }

      /**
       * Validate hex with regular expression
       * @param hex hex for validation
       * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
       */
      public boolean validate(final String hex){

          matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
          return matcher.matches();

      }
}
```

pattern have to is :

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

if you want more explanation say to me.